# $_ENV - пустое значение

Tags: php

Пишу

```
print_r($_ENV);
```

И выводит пустой массив

Пробую так еще

```
print_r($GLOBALS);
```

Так-же выводит пустой суперглобальный массив $_ENV

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27077452/5280485

Comment: @user190134: От себя добавляю, если у вас не Apache, а связка Nginx + PHP-FPM, то в конфиге fpm `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` необходимо добавить параметр `clear_env = no`. Для PHP-FPM 5.3 этот параметр отсутствует, т.е. по умолчанию переменные окружения доступны.